# How to initialize preference datastore class in fragment to get saved data from login in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-databinding, android-jetpack-datastore

as I'm new to kotlin and data store preference so I'm putting this question in a hope to get some proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
// At the top level of your kotlin file:
val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")
```

Based on the [doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#preferences-create), you call this once at the top level of your kotlin file, and then you can use it throughout your project.

To read and write from the datastore, just call `context.datastore`, like this:

READ:

```
val EXAMPLE_COUNTER = intPreferencesKey("example_counter")
val exampleCounterFlow: Flow<Int> = context.dataStore.data
  .map { preferences ->
    // No type safety.
    preferences[EXAMPLE_COUNTER] ?: 0
}
```

WRITE:

```
suspend fun incrementCounter() {
  context.dataStore.edit { settings ->
    val currentCounterValue = settings[EXAMPLE_COUNTER] ?: 0
    settings[EXAMPLE_COUNTER] = currentCounterValue + 1
  }
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful but I'm still not getting how to initialize the preference-data-store class in fragment to get the user-id and auth-key in the same.